# получение расширения файла из строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть строка:
**some-file-name.mov** или **some-another-file.some.jpeg**

Сейчас я для того чтобы получить расширение файла, использую такой код:

```
const type = 'video/' + file.title
    .split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('')
    .split('.')[0]
    .split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('');

//mov  
//jpeg
```

Как заменить код более лаконичным выражением, например используя регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function ext(name) {
  var m = name.match(/\.([^.]+)$/)
  return m && m[1]
}

console.log(ext("some-file-name.mov"))
console.log(ext("some-another-file.some.jpeg"))
console.log(ext("nothing"))
```

Если хочется в одну строчку, то можно так:

```js
function ext(name) {
  return name.match(/\.([^.]+)$|$/)[1]
}

console.log(ext("some-file-name.mov"))
console.log(ext("some-another-file.some.jpeg"))
console.log(ext("nothing"))
```

или, если позволяет поддержка современного js:

```js
function ext(name) {
  return name.match(/\.([^.]+)$/)?.[1]
}

console.log(ext("some-file-name.mov"))
console.log(ext("some-another-file.some.jpeg"))
console.log(ext("nothing"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно гораздо короче: `file_name.split('.').reverse()[0]`.

```js
let str1 = 'smomlsdf.jpg';
let str2 = 'sdlfjsng.mov';

function getExtension(file_name){
        return file_name.split('.').reverse()[0];
}

console.log(getExtension(str1));
console.log(getExtension(str2));
```

Если через регулярные, то: `file_name.match(/\.([a-zA-Z]+)$/)[1]`.

```js
let str1 = 'sdfl.s.momlsdf.jpg';
let str2 = 'sdlfjsng.mov';

function getExtension(file_name){
    return file_name.match(/\.([a-zA-Z]+)$/)[1];
}

console.log(getExtension(str1));
console.log(getExtension(str2));
```

Comment: `somestring.split('.').pop()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, тоже вариант!